# Setting an image file as background

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that extends JFrame and contains 3 panels + another one that holds all the 3 panels together in a layout.

```
panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add("North", panel2); //row of buttons
    panel.add("Center",grid); // grid of buttons
    panel.add("South",panel3); // a textfield that stretches across the total width of the frame
    add(panel);



    JLabel background = new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("C:\\.png"));
    background.setBounds (0,0,500,550);
    add(background);
    //the background for the frame


    setVisible (true);
    setResizable (false);
    setBounds (398,70, 570, 620);
    setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

My problem is the program gives me an output with the background image/image in the jlabel only visible or somehow overshadowing the panels/making the buttons invisible. I need the background image to be behind the buttons, I mean that's why it's called a background What am I missing?

- I'm not using a container because well this isn't going to be set up as an applet any time soon and idk if that reason suffices but yeah

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to achieve is, is to simply make the `JLabel` the content pane of the frame...

```
JLabel background =  new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("C:\\.png"));
setContentPane(background);
```

The next that arise from this is the fact the `JLabel` has no layout manager by default, making adding you other content to it a bit difficult (or at least, not result in what you're hoping for), so next, you need to set the layout manager...

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // Forwarded to the content pane...
```

Then you can add all your content happily...

```
add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH); //row of buttons
add(grid); // grid of buttons
add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // a textfield that
```

The next issue you might have is the fact that most components are opaque, so you might want to call `setOpaque(false)` on the components you are adding if you're hoping to see the background...

And finally...

```
setVisible (true);
setResizable (false);
```

This will cause you some issues, instead, try using...

```
setResizable(false);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

ps- `JLabel` does not automatically resize the image, but pack should help...assuming the rest of the content fits within the size of the background image...

Comment: I'm not using a container though?

Comment: From edit to question *"I'm not using a container because well this isn't going to be set up as an applet.."*  ?!?  You seem to think a 'container' is something very different to what it actually is.  Admittedly, [`Applet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) does inherit functionality from [`Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) but then, so does almost everything else that appears on-screen in a Java GUI (whether it is an embedded applet, or a free floating frame).

Comment: OH sorry I was referring to `Container c = getContentPane();` but okay. Yeah  I tried removing the panel that holds all the 3 panels together and added the background but the background became invisible but I'll try again

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I am indeed mistaken; my instructor told me I needed the `Container c = getContentPane();` to be able to display my program when it is set up for an applet and that what I was referring to, I might have been confused by it sorry

Comment: Your instructor is way out of date.  It has not been necessary to explicitly call for the content pane for a long time.  But on that subject, both `JApplet` and `JFrame` have a content pane.

Comment: Components that extend from JPanel are opaque by default, tank I said that. You need to use setOpaque(false) to make them transparent